# sudo: npm: command not found, while running npm with sudo

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I installed nodejs v8.11.2 and npm v5.6.0 using the command `nvm install 8.11.2`.

When I opened my system after shutting it down for a while my system and wrote `npm -v` in the terminal, it said npm is not installed, and to install it with `sudo apt install npm`.

However when I again entered `nvm install 8.11.2`, it said that nodejs and npm are already installed and it began using it. Sometimes when opening a different terminal, `npm -v` says that npm is not installed. And later when I used the command `sudo npm install`, the output came:

> ```
> sudo: npm: command not found
> ```

So I installed npm with `sudo apt-get install npm`, but it installed npm v3.5.2 and updating it with `npm install npm@latest -g` did nothing, i.e., it remained npm v3.5.2.

I need npm v5.6.0 for a project of mine and is clueless on how to get this issue sorted. Please help.

Comment: Try this link:
https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-multiple-versions-node-nvm/

Comment: I still cannot get the desired version with sudo. It's not mentioned in the article either. When I tried using nvm with sudo, the output came: 

`sudo: nvm: command not found`
@udayakumar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(nvm maintainer here)

1. `sudo` is not, and must not be, used with `nvm`. `nvm` is per-user, per-shell.
2. `npm` should not be installed by itself; it comes with node. You should apt-get remove it.
3. If nvm isn't being loaded properly on a new shell, try rerunning the install script, then file an issue on http://nvm.sh, and I'll be happy to help you directly.

Comment: This doesn't address why, if following the above,  you still get 'sudo: npm: command not found' if you want to run 'sudo npm install'

Comment: because `sudo` brings you into an entirely distinct user profile that doesn't have nvm. don't use sudo.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to make both these links:

```
sudo ln -s "$(which npm)" /usr/bin/npm

sudo ln -s "$(which node)" /usr/bin/node
```

See [user14219984's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51536330/sudo-npm-command-not-found-in-wsl)