# sudo: npm: command not found in WSL

Tags: node.js, sudo, windows-subsystem-for-linux, oh-my-zsh, nvm

I'm trying to install globally some packages for my Unix environment on Windows with WSL. I use `nvm` to manage the different versions of Node.js.

The problem is while using the `sudo` command before a global npm install :

`sudo npm install --global prompt-pure`

I get an error: `sudo: npm: command not found` !

[image: WSL sudo node npm command not found]

Doing a simple `npm install --global pure-prompt` will work, but as I'm not super user, the global installation ends up with a permission error.

How can I fix this annoying problem and keep `nvm` ?

Thanks by advance

Comment: Add the current user to sudoers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you try to run `sudo npm`, it tries to run the npm binary file `/usr/bin/npm` but your binary is located in a different place, which can be found running `which npm`.

Example: /home/damo/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/bin/npm

The solution is to create a link in `/usr/bin/` pointing to the actual binary:

`sudo ln -s "$(which npm)" /usr/bin/npm`

You can also add the following link so you can run `sudo node`

`sudo ln -s "$(which node)" /usr/bin/node`

Comment: apparently this beauty  has other opinion...  `-bash: /npm: No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/npm' -> '': No such file or directory`

Comment: @DobromirKirov you first need to confirm the location of your npm binary with `which npm`. Or, you can manually tell the location of your binary. From my example above it would be: `sudo ln -s /home/damo/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm`

Answer (score 1):

For me I needed to actually cheat and run as `root` before installing node as `root`. For this I ran `sudo su` in a Ubuntu WSL term and then installed node.

Once I did that I could `sudo su` then `npm run special-script`.

I don't know a better way to get a script to attach to restricted ports like 443 for testing https connections but it works.

Comment: Thanks!. Works for me to install serverless: `sudo su`, `apt install npm`, `npm i -g serverless` next y `exit` the sudo user and confirm installation with `serverless -v`.

Answer (score 0):

As you will find in the man file for sudo `man sudo` sudo will execute a command as another user. That other user has a different home directory to you and access to different commands

When i run `sudo which node` i get nothing, but `which node` returns /home/damo/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/bin/node

Lets look at your actual goal. You say you are trying to install pure-prompt, i know this does not ask your explicit question but given you have zsh installed have you tried oh-my-zsh (https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) i use this on every install of linux i ever have to work with (VMs, WSL, docker). Very customizable and looks great out of the box.